# VSCode Prettier Line Length format does not work

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, prettier

Im working on a C# file

I downloaded prettier extension
In VS Code I Go to Settings- Default formatter and select Prettier

I checked the Prettier line length settings are set to 80 characters max

I even tried enabling format on save

nothing works, when I rick click and Format Document, or Format Document with, nothing changes in my code

I also tried the same thing with Clang and Installing LLVM

Nothing works

[image]

Comment: Remove the `clang` tag; it indicates discussion about a particular C-Language tool.  This is C#, not C.

Comment: doesnt clang work for C#

Comment: I don't think so.  If you look at the _tag wiki_ for `clang` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clang), it's a particular tool for `C`